# PHPMAILER ejecuta todo menos $mail->Send();

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

estoy con un script para informar de la falta de stock mediante e-mail y no hay manera de hacerlo funcionar llevo todo el dia con este problema y no hay manera de hacerlo funcionar.

colo cando echos ejecuta absolutamente todo menos el Send();

Ademas estoy usando la ultima version de php mayler que deveria de ser la mas estable y en el proyecto de un compañero funciona pero este no los tenemos casi iguales y no funciona.

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    if ($_GET[id]!='') {
        require('conexion.php');
        require 'class.phpmailer.php';
        $id = $_GET[id];
        $select=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Cantidad FROM g_stock WHERE Id = '$id'");
        $cantidad=mysqli_fetch_array($select);
        if($cantidad['Cantidad']>0){
            $sql = "UPDATE g_stock SET Cantidad=Cantidad-1 WHERE Id = '$id'";
            if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                echo "OK";
            } else {
                echo "Error operando registro";
            }
            $select1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Cantidad, Cantidad_minima FROM g_stock WHERE Id = '$id'");
            $cantidad=mysqli_fetch_array($select1);
            echo $cantidad;
            if ($cantidad['Cantidad'] <= $cantidad['Cantidad_minima']){
                $id=$_GET[id];
                $select3=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM g_stock WHERE Id = '$id'");
                $articulo=mysqli_fetch_array($select3);
                $mensaje="<p>Se acaba de reducir el stock de ".$articulo['Articulo']." ahora mismo hay ".$articulo['Cantidad']." unidades de ".$articulo['Cantidad_minima']."que deberia haber como minimo.</p>";
                $mail = new PHPMailer;
                $mail->IsSMTP();
                $mail->Host = 'smtp.x.x'; 
                $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
                $mail->From = 'email 1@gmail.com';
                $mail->Username = 'email 1@gmail.com';
                $mail->FromName = 'Web ERP';
                $mail->Password ='pass';
                $mail->AddAddress('email2@mail.com');
                $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 
                $mail->IsHTML(true); 
                $mail->Subject = "Mensaje de falta de Stock";
                $mail->Body = $mensaje;
                echo $mail->Body;
                /*?>
                    <script>console.log('<?php echo $mail; ?>');</script>
                <?php*/
                $exito = $mail->Send();
                echo $exito;
                /*if(!$mail->Send()) {
                   echo "<span style='color:red;'>Tu mensaje no se ha podido enviar. EscrĂ­benos a xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>";
                   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                }*/
            }
            mysqli_close($con);
            header('Location: ../stock.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: te recomiendo cambiar las credenciales

Comment: echo me he dado cuenta nad amas darle a publicar ;)

Comment: puedes agregar el `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` antes del `send` para validar el porque no se envia

Comment: tambien puedes ver el log de apache y ver el error que te arroja

Comment: solo tengo acceso por ftp al hosting y en la consola de chrome no da errores